# No match for ‘boost::shared_ptr::operator=’

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

This is the code I have that causes the error below:

```cpp
class CAlternateMerchantList
{
public:
    CAlternateMerchant::SP m_pAlternateMerchantList[MAX_PLAYER_LIST];
    int m_nMax;
    int m_nCur;

    CAlternateMerchantList()
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < MAX_PLAYER_LIST; i++)
            m_pAlternateMerchantList[i] = NULL;
        m_nMax = 0;
        m_nCur = 0;
    }
```

The error I get is the following:

```
PersonalShop.h: In constructor ‘CAlternateMerchantList::CAlternateMerchantList()’:
PersonalShop.h:227: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘((CAlternateMerchantList*)this)->CAlternateMerchantList::m_pAlternateMerchantList[i] = 0’
/usr/local/include/boost-1_65_1/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:547: note: candidates are: boost::shared_ptr<T>& boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator=(const boost::shared_ptr<T>&) [with T = CAlternateMerchant]
```

As you can see, I'm using `boost 1_65_1` libraries. If I am not wrong, this code worked on another system with `boost 1_59`, but at the moment I can not access it for testing.

Does anyone know how to make this code work with boost 1.65? Or, is there any other issue here?

Comment: Does it work if you replace macro `NULL` with keyword `nullptr`?

Comment: Then I get `"PersonalShop.h:224: error: ‘nullptr’ was not declared in this scope"`
Is it possible that my gcc version is invalid?
Thanks for your quick reply!

Comment: If your compiler doesn't know what `nullptr` is then either it's time to put it out to grass or maybe tell it what C++ version you want it to compile for on the command line.  What does `gcc --version` report?

Comment: Old compiler for old game, 4.4.7, maybe I should update that at some point

Comment: @Whothefk Yes, I would.  If you own the code and can fix any issues that arise then you owe it to yourself to move on.  PS: time to master the `@` tagging trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to set `boost::shared_ptr`s to null. They have a [default constructor](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/libs/smart_ptr/doc/html/smart_ptr.html#shared_ptr_default_constructor) which does it automatically. You can simply delete the entire `for` loop.

I suggest also using an [initialization list](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/when-do-we-use-initializer-list-in-c/) for `m_nMax` and `m_nCur`.

```
CAlternateMerchantList()
    : m_nMax(0), m_nCur(0)
{
}
```

Comment: So I don't have to reset `m_pAlternateMerchantList` to NULL at all? Great, thanks for your help!

Comment: @Whothefk You don't have to _set_ it, no, but you might at some point elect to [`reset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/reset) it.  Catchy username, BTW.

Answer (score 4):

You are likely compiling for an older C++ version, as evident by your compiler not understanding what `nullptr` is.

Prior to C++11, `NULL` is an alias for an integer literal `0`, which can be assigned to raw pointers, but `boost::shared_ptr` can't be assigned an integer.

In C++11 and later, `NULL` is (typically) an alias for the `nullptr` keyword, and `boost::shared_ptr` can be assigned, and constructed from, `nullptr`.

In any case, as [John Kugelman explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72193077/65863), you don't need to initialize your array's smart pointer elements to `NULL`/`nullptr` to begin with, as they are already initialized to that state for you by `boost::shared_ptr`'s default constructor.  So just remove your `for` loop altogether.

Comment: "_In C++11 and later, NULL is an alias for the nullptr keyword_": This is not required. The old implementation as integral literal is still allowed as well. So it should not be relied on and instead `nullptr` always used.